# How do I set HTML page title using Excel VBA Macro?

Tags: html, excel, vba

```
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\example\Desktop\AutoOutput\test"+ ".html", _
        FileFormat:=xlHtml, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

^the macro script to save

I have a excel table that i save into HTML format to share.

I want to apply a page title (what you see on your browser tab/window when you open the web page). I know you can save via excel and have that option via manual save

How do I do it via macro?

Can't find similar question online

[image]

Comment: never used macro , there is a way to edit your html file with your script ? if not why not a js script that add title tag if he missing whe the page is loaded ?

Comment: I want it done within Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications, not sure how I can add js script to that. 
Possible that an option is to edit+add the title in to the html file after it is saved using VBA, but I'm not sure how, also not sure if its possible if they did not have a title to edit in the first place. 
maybe add a "<title>test</title> to after a <html> tag?

Comment: give a look to this and tell me if that can solve you bug : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371990/how-do-i-replace-a-string-in-a-line-of-a-text-file-using-filesystemobject-in-vba

Comment: oh wow this actually work ! thanks, writing the solution here in a few mins

Comment: happy to read that

Comment: edit, this work around causes some issue

Answer (score 1):

```
'auto save
       ChDir "C:\Example\AutoOutput\" + TestDate()
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Example\AutoOutput\" + TestDate() + "filename.html", _
        FileFormat:=xlHtml, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
```

^Saving the file as html, normally

```
        
        
        'Declare ALL of your variables :)
     Dim fileToRead As String
     Dim fileToWrite As String
Const ForReading = 1    '
 fileToRead = "C:\Example\AutoOutput\" + TestDate() + "filename.html"   ' the path of the file to read
 fileToWrite = "C:\Example\AutoOutput\" + TestDate() + "filename.html"   ' the path of a new file
Dim FSO As Object
Dim readFile As Object  'the file you will READ
Dim writeFile As Object 'the file you will CREATE
Dim repLine As Variant   'the array of lines you will WRITE
Dim ln As Variant
Dim l As Long

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set readFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(fileToRead, ForReading, False)


'# Read entire file into an array & close it
repLine = Split(readFile.ReadAll, vbNewLine)
readFile.Close

'# iterate the array and do the replacement line by line
For Each ln In repLine
    ln = IIf(InStr(1, ln, "</head>", vbTextCompare) > 0, Replace(ln, "</head>", "</head><title>YOUR TITLE, FINALLY</title>"), ln)
    repLine(l) = ln
    l = l + 1
Next

'close excel (if not you cant overwrite)
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
        
        Set writeFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(fileToWrite, True, False)
'# Write to the array items to the file
writeFile.Write Join(repLine, vbNewLine)
writeFile.Close

'# clean up
Set readFile = Nothing
Set writeFile = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
```

^This part is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371990/how-do-i-replace-a-string-in-a-line-of-a-text-file-using-filesystemobject-in-vba), but it is modified by me so that it can write on current file rather than new file

```
Workbooks.Open "C:\Example\AutoOutput\" + TestDate() + "filename.html"
 
    Shell "explorer.exe " + "C:\Example\AutoOutput\" + TestDate() + "filename.html"
```

^opening the work that is done.

### Very extensive steps to put a page title ><

Thanks Code Scooper for the suggestion in comment,
I used his suggestion [How do I Replace a String in a Line of a Text File Using FileSystemObject in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371990/how-do-i-replace-a-string-in-a-line-of-a-text-file-using-filesystemobject-in-vba) ,
to try out my idea of replacing 1 singular tag,

in this case `</head>`,
and replace it with itself + new title:
`</head><title>YOUR TITLE, FINALLY</title>`

I also modified the code a bit so that I can make it able overwrite itself. as I didn't want filename.html and filename2.html

Not sure if there could've been a simpler solution, if there are and u happen to find it do add it here. For now I'm happy that it works. There wasn't much stuff in `Filename:= "C:\Example\filename.html", FileFormat:=xlHtml, ...`, probably this work-around solution is it.

**EDIT:**
edit, I get some minor font color lost saving it this way.and even if I open the one with title already and save it again, the title is lost while the font color returns. look like this is a bad walkaround
edit, manage to fix it by applying font color manually instead of to hyperlinks type. very poor method overall.

Comment: nice ^^ , happy to help you